# Pressure on side walls of container

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-statics

My textbook mentions the standard derivation of finding pressure at a depth of a liquid  by considering a cylindrical portion of liquid an then using the equilibrium of forces and hence pressure comes out  to be $$hdg$$.What I want to ask is that the above method is correct but then it is mentioned that pressure on a point of side wall at a depth of $$h$$ would also be $$hdg$$ without giving any explanation. If I try to use the above stated derivation then there is problem that I can't use the weight since gravity acts downward and also I don't know the force exerted by fluid on side walls. So how can I say that pressure at depth is same as pressure on side walls?

Answer (score 2):

Pressure at a depth in a liquid is equal to the pressure exerted by the liquid on a surfce at that depth in the liquid.Because pressure at a point is the same in all directions and if the liquid particles exert a pressure on each other then they exert the same pressure on any other surface immersed at that depth.